# x3d - what blend modes to use

Tags: 3d, x3d

What blend modes and attributes must I use to achieve following effect:

First texture is a tileable grass texture and second texture is the opacity mask for that texture.

```
<MultiTexture mode='"MODULATE" "?"'>
    <ImageTexture repeatS="true" repeatT="true" url='"grass.jpg"' />
    <ImageTexture url='"grass_opacity.png"' />
    <MultiTextureTransform>
        <TextureTransform scale="8 8"/>
        <TextureTransform/>
    </MultiTextureTransform>
</MultiTexture>
```

Using: `"SELECTARG2, SELECTARG1"` seems only to work with hard masks, either 0 or 100% opacity.

Using Bs Contact player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct blending is:

```
<MultiTexture mode='"SELECTARG2,SELECTARG1" "BLENDCURRENTALPHA,DIFFUSE_SELECTARG2"'>
```

but Bs Contact player does not supports it in x3d file format. With vml its no problem.